# Node.js - Oracle DB and fetchAsString format

Tags: node.js

I am stuck on a problem and I am not sure what is the best way to solve it. I have a date column that I want to select and I want to fetch it as a string. Which is great, node-oracledb module has this option with `fetchAsString` mehotd. But it fetches the date like this for example `10-JAN-16` and I want to fetch it like this `10-01-2016`. Is there a way to do that from the node-oracledb module, or I should modify the date after I get the result from the query?

UPDATE: I mean solution without to_char in the query and without query modifications

Comment: In the select statement, you can use to_char function to change the format.

Comment: I am sorry @notionquest, I updated my question. I meant without using query modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this section of my series on Working with Dates in JavaScript, JSON, and Oracle Database:
https://dzone.com/articles/working-with-dates-using-the-nodejs-driver

The logon trigger shows an example of using alter session to set the default date format. Keep in mind that there is NLS_DATE_FORMAT, NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT, NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT.

I only show NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT because I convert to that type in the examples that follow as I need to do some time zone conversion for the date format I'm using.

Another way to set the NLS parameters is to use environment variables of the same name. Note that this method will not work unless you set the NLS_LANG environment variable as well.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for, thank you @Dan McGhan